# Prolog lists splitting

Tags: list, prolog, visual-prolog

I have function:

```
onlySecond([],[]).

onlySecond([H1,H2|T1],[H2|T2]) :- onlySecond(T1,T2).
```

It returns every second element in the list.

But i'm curious why it is not returning nothing (on my opinion, it must return [] - empty list) when first argument is list with 1 element. Example:

```
onlySecond([1],X). - not return anything.. but why it doesn't return []??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has a bigger problem: it returns `false` for any list of odd size. The reason for it is that there is no clause of `onlySecond/2` that would unify with a list that has exactly one item - a condition that you would necessarily reach when you start with a list that has an odd number of items, because each recursive invocation reduces the length of the original list by two:

- it does not unify with the first clause, because `[1]` is *not* an empty list
- it does not unify with the second clause, because `[1]` has fewer than two items.

In order to fix this problem, add a separate clause to deal with a list that has exactly one item:

```
onlySecond([_], []).
```

Adding this clause makes your code work for lists of odd length as well.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/LEFeoO)